# Importing a function from up in the tree

Tags: python, import

I'd like to execute a line such as:

```
from ....file import function
```

I'm working with a Git repository an I'm only supposed to edit in the folder my file is in. Using the above method results in:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Are there ways to achieve what I need? I could just copy the function but it should be imported in case of further development. I tried to fiddle with local repository and add an **init**.py file to every folder up to the root of the project to make it into a package (or so I read) but it didn't work as well, resulting in the same error.

Comment: To quote from the pop-up text on the [tag:git] tag: "do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository."

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from file import function
```

This should do the trick.